# How to save the mysqldump file on remote server

Tags: mysql

I am using mysqldump to create the backup and save to the .sql file. I know how to use mysqldump to save the dump data to a file.

However I am in a trouble now. When I connect to any MySql Server to create and the backup file, it saves the file on the server where the MysqlDump resides. I need to save the file on the server where the MySql server resides.
So for example I have MySqlDump on host(or Ip) A and the MySql server is residing on host(or ip) B, then after connecting the MySql server, the file is saved on host(or ip) A, rather than to save on the host(or ip) B. I want to save the file on host(or ip) B. Is there any way? can I do that with all MySql Server located on different host over the internet. Please help me

Comment: Why not run the mysql dump on the server where MySQL resides? Or, just scp the file from Server A to Server B.

Comment: Mike your suggestion cannot work in my case. I am using MySqlDump in a service which is developed in Perl language and this service will be hosted on one server and will run on daily basis and will connect different servers dynamically, by extracting server infos from db.

Answer (score 2):

IP of Local Server = 10.1.2.20

IP of Remote Server = 10.1.2.30

If you have mysql installed on the remote server, then you could login to 10.1.2.30 and run mysqldump using the local server's IP:

```
mysqldump -h10.1.2.20 -u... -p... --all-databases > /root/MySQLData.sql
```

Perhaps doing this via ssh

```
ssh 10.1.2.30 mysqldump -h10.1.2.20 -u... -p... --all-databases > /root/MySQLData.sql
```

Comment: but here is the different issue. I am creating a service in Perl which will be deployed on linux server and which will use MySqlDump to create db backups across different MySql Servers, which will be hosted on different servers. And I need to save the backup file in .sql format over the Remote MySql Server. So if there are different MySqlSrver on different hosts, the backup should be created and then saved on the same server where the MySql server hosts.